# Different networks with different NICs (more details inside)

Tags: windows-7, networking, ethernet, file-sharing

I have two computers: a desktop (Windows 7 Professional) with an ethernet jack in the motherboard and room for another (PCI or USB) and a laptop (Win7 Home Premium) with an ethernet jack. Internet connectivity is available through an ethernet wall jack (no access to switch/router). If I were to purchase a second NIC for the desktop (and have ample ethernet cables), would a setup meeting the following criteria be possible? If so, how?

- Desktop has connection to internet through wall
- File sharing is possible (both ways) between the two computers (default Windows network sharing and drive mapping)
- The laptop is not connected to the LAN coming from the wall (from the network administrator's POV - only one of the two devices can be connected at any time)
- Not necessary, but nice: a way to choose which folders are shared to which network. On the desktop, which would be connected to both the internet/building LAN and the laptop, there are some folders which I would rather only be available to the laptop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed a second NIC in the desktop computer, you could connect the laptop to the network through the desktop with a simple [crossover cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable). You can either make one yourself or, if you are unsure of your cable crafting abilities, can be purchased online or from many office supply stores.

This would require a little network configuration on your end to make it work out, but there are a few methods to do it outlined [online](http://www.wikihow.com/Connect-Two-Computers).